# opencart add more more brands link in 3rd level category

Tags: hyperlink, opencart, categories

using this code

`$sisters = array_slice($sisters, 0, 5);`

in `catalog/controller/module/category.php`

I'm displaying only 5 sister categories. I'm having a trouble  adding a link stating `View More` which should link their parent category underneath all sister categories having more than 5 entries.

Any suggestion to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php if ($child['children1']) { $j=0; ?>
                                <?php  foreach ($child['children1'] as $child1) { $j++; ?>
                             <?php if($j>2) { ?><li class="level-2-cat-list-sub-cat"><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>">More...</a></li><?php break; } else { ?>
                                  <li class="level-2-cat-list-sub-cat" id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                     <a href="<?php echo $child1['href1']; ?>"><?php echo strtolower(ucwords($child1['name1'])); ?></a> 
                                  </li>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                            <?php } ?>
```

Make  the not on above .tpl file there $j was declared and if it was greater than 2 More... was printed with and anchor tag and ended with "break;" statement